# Use of multiple jedis connection in jedis sentinel pool

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redis, jedis

I am implementing jedis in spring web app.
I need to know should i get jedis from pool resource once and use it every time in controller or should i get new jedis from pool every time controller is called and close it again.
As i go through documentation we should not be using same jedis connection in multi threaded environment so question arises we should get jedis connection form resource pool in controller or we should use one created in spring service

Configuration is in application contex

```
<bean id="jedisService" class="com.til.ibeat.service.JedisService">
</bean>
```

Spring controller

```
<bean id="cacheRedisController" class="com.controller.CacheControllerRedis">
    <property name="jedisService"><ref bean="jedisService"/> </property>
</bean>
```

Code in jedis service

```
int database = 0;
        JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        // poolConfig.setMaxActive(1000);
        poolConfig.setMaxIdle(10);
        poolConfig.setMinIdle(1);
        // poolConfig.setMaxWait(30000);
        poolConfig.setNumTestsPerEvictionRun(10);
        poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        poolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);
        poolConfig.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        poolConfig.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
        int timeout = 300;
        pool = new JedisSentinelPool(Config.REDIS_PROD_USER, Config.CONNECTION_REDIS, poolConfig, timeout, Config.REDIS_PROD_USER_PASSWORD,
                database);
        try {
            jedis = pool.getResource();
        //  Socket socket = jedis.getClient().getSocket();
        //  System.out.println("Connected to " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());

        } catch (JedisException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (jedis != null) {
                jedis.close();
                pool.destroy();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should create pool once and get new Jedis from pool every time for operation and close it again.**

Pool is your resource manager. You should not create it over and over again. Pool should be created once and (re)used to get resources, specially in a multi-threaded environment.

Jedis is your resource. You should get it before your every operation and return (close) it afterwards. Try to avoid doing multiple operations after getting one resource (Jedis) because this unbalances resource sharing.

So, for your application:

```
// Do this once, may be at the beginning of application
pool = new JedisSentinelPool(...);

// For every operation
jedis = pool.getResource();
// Do your operation(s)
jedis.close();

// Once, at the end of application
pool.destroy();
```